# How to Enter Multi value float at a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to enter a multi value float at a single column in mysql. I have a table in which there are three fields : `type` , `unit` and `value`. The `type` and `unit` are `strings` and contains things like - `bmi,weight,pressure` and `kg/m2,kg` etc. respectively. In the value column I want to enter float values which will be respective to the other two columns. Like - `bmi - kg/m2 - 20.0`

Similarly `weight - kg - 65.5` etc.

For example - if there is a primary key `id` then the `value` column of `id = 1` will contain - `89.3, 56 and 23.56` .

I tried to do it similarly like it is done in string using `commans(,)` but that didn't worked and an error came : `Data truncated at column 'value' at row 1`

A little code snippet will be extremely helpful. I tried to search about this but as I am completely new to mysql and databases and I don't have any idea about how to insert more than single value for a specific row at a column therefore, I am struggling in this simple question. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was me, and I was trying to implement an EAV model, then I'd have separate tables for integer type things and decimal type things

Comment: @Strawberry Actually there are already three tables and this table is actually being used as a medical data. It has the tests , their respective measurements and values. I am not able to insert multi value according to the other columns. There might be a way to input multiple values at  a float column in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what multi value float means but you can insert multiple rows/columns like this

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE ('type', 'unit', 'value') VALUES ('bmi', 'kg/m2', 20.0),
('weight', 'kg', 65.5)
```

Comment: What I mean by multi value is that : the primary key is suppose 'id' and that id has three columns as mentioned above. So in a column three values are to be entered and that column has a float datatype.

Comment: like for id - 1 the column value contains three values - 87.0 , 65.2 and 56.24 . That is what I am asking.

Comment: Its not possible to add 3 separate float values into a single column with a float data type. Either the data type has to be changed to varchar and then you can add a delimiter like a pipe '|'  to separate out values
 or a better solution would be to store the float values in a new table which will join with the primary table as suggested by @Strawberry

Comment: OK I understood that. I went through some resources .Thank You

Comment: @Chaos the best way is change data type to varchar and then store it with comma separated. 

Answer (score 0):

See first of all you have to make your table properly for Float value.While creating `column value` you must focus on `lenght/value field` of phpMyadmin you have to put like this(20,20) in example below i have taken (23,19).it show how many digit you want after decimal point see below code and screen shot.

```
1.insert query
$sql="INSERT INTO `test_user` (`type`, `unit`, `value`) VALUES ('weight', 'kg', '20.5')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);//
if($result){
echo "inserted sucessfully";
}else{
echo "unable to insert";
}
```

2.see the table[image] structure of the table(column value)[image: structure].

Comment: This doesn't provide me the solution. You might have misunderstood my question.

Comment: There is a primary 'id' and the above columns. Then for id - 1 I want three values in the values column - 89.8 , 76.3 and 12.0 in float format. That is my question . How to do it?  This is just an example.

Comment: see, as you eleborate now,i am not able to understand can you please put the structutre of db in your question

Comment: It's fine what I have been trying to do is not possible with float type so either I have to convert it to String or varchar or I have to make a separate table. Thank You for the contribution.